# Checking if a follower has been added to my twitter account

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm losing my mind. I'm unable to figure out the logic to determine if a follower has been added to my twitter account. I want a service to be running which checks my current followers, then when a new followers follows my account to perform an action. If no change has occured just say no change. Below is my main.py

```
import tweepy
import logging
from config import create_api

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

def get_friends(api, old, new):
    user = api.get_user('UserX')
    new = user.followers_count
    if new == old:
        print('No Change')
        old = new
        return old
    else: 
        print('Follower was added')
        old = new
        return old

def main():
    api = create_api()
    user = api.get_user('UserX')
    old = user.followers_count
    new = user.followers_count
    while True:

        get_friends(api, old, new)
        logger.info('Waiting...')
        time.sleep(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Below is my config.py

```
import tweepy
import logging
import os

logger = logging.getLogger()

def create_api():
    consumer_key= ''
    consumer_secret= ''
    access_token= ''
    access_token_secret= ''
    
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
        wait_on_rate_limit_notify=False)
    
    try:
        api.verify_credentials()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("Error creating API", exc_info=True)
        raise e
    logger.info("API created")
    return api
```

Comment: Hi, what are you expecting the program to do, and what is the program actually doing?

Comment: whyd od you use `==` in `new == old` ? Maybe you means `new = old`? Or better `old = new`

Comment: I want the program to first initialize the amount of followers against account. Then, go an get followers compare old value to new value. If old value and new value are equal then print No Change. If the value is not the same or better yet increased then print Friend has been added.

Comment: @furas to compare 2 numbers for equality you do need ==, = is for assignment

Comment: @user3066155 maybe you need to do user = api.get_user('userX') again to update the user object, does that work?

Comment: @Luke_ but there was line `new == old` (after `print()`) without `if ...: ... else ...` and it was useless. Now I see OP changed these lines and now there is  `new = old`

Comment: There is no userX. I removed my user account. Correct I changed the code.

Comment: so does it work now?